# Can I capture all packets to/from a router?

Tags: wireshark, packet, capture

I have a router connected to a number of devices through DHCP. I face frequent internet disconnection issues as I believe some kind of DOS attacks choke my port. Is there any way I can capture all packets being transmitted to my WAN IP through a software like Wireshark for Windows?

If not, how do I diagnose the issue?

Comment: Configure a mirror port on the router or add a device in front of that port that will do the capture for you (e.g. a computer with two network interface). This will probably require some kind of modem or similar depending on how your WAN works.

Comment: Is port mirror same as port mapping? I can’t find any port mirroring option on my router however I do see a port mapping one. I got a Huawei HG8247H

Comment: That looks like a SOHO device. I haven't really seen one that allows you to configure port mirroring. With port mirroring any traffic you receive on one port is replicated to another one in addition to being processed.